# Share generated private/public pair among instances of same application

Tags: java, jwt, secret-sharing

I've been working on a login system which works with [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). Nothing fancy, you send a valid pair user+password and then you get a signed token to identify yourself on further requests. It is build on Java. For signing the tokens, the application generates a public/private pair of keys on run time, and exposes the public key on a given URL. This was made this way because there is a wide, and growing, number of services that need to validate the tokens, and makes it easier to distribute the public key.

The issue I'm facing now is that this application will be deployed on more than just one node, for redundancy and downtime prevention. In this context, if every instance of the application generates a pair of keys, then the whole system breaks apart. So I need to make sure one node generates a pair, and then shares it with the others.

So far, my ideas had gone around saving them somewhere in the database, or use the shared values on a [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.13/zookeeperInternals.html) cluster, but I'm not sure it is the right approach.

To sum up... the context:

- JWT signing with private/public key pairs generated on run time
- Multiple nodes, needs to be aware of same pair

the question:

- Is there something in the idea severely wrong that makes this nonviable?
- Is there a standard way of doing this?
- Are there any better ideas than using the database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's a number of SSO (Single Sign On) solutions already available. Why are you attending to create your own?  If it's just for fun that's one thing, but it sounds like this is for a production system.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Daisetsu. I did thought about Auth0 first, and maybe I did not understand it, but there where some specific requirements that we could not seem to meet with such solution. One of them is the physical territory where the data is stored. The business is heavily regulated by the law. Could you mention some I might have missed? It just needs to be running locally (in our own data centers).

Comment: Kerberos has been around for a long time. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/single-signon.html